# passing parameters to resource factory in angularjs from controller to search in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, meanjs

### Explanation

I have a textbox in view that choose which model to be displayed. 
I need to pass a variable from view to the angular resource factory, to be passed to the Server Controller to decide which model should be passed to the Client Controller.

As you see I pass a variable called **issuename** to resource and then I expect to choose the model in controller by the magnitude of this parameter.

I type Jeans in the textbox in view which means that **issuename** should be equal to Jeans and it should give me the SAME result as when I assign the value of **searchParam** to Jeans manually.

BUT it seems like it is not passed properly because when I comment out that line in Server Controller I cannot see Jeans model anymore.

I have tried:

1. req.body.issuename
2. req.params.issuename
3. req.issuename

And still it is not working So there should be another problem

Thanks in advance for your help!

### Code Section

Client Service ( $resource )

```
angular.module('alls').factory('Alls', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('alls/:issuename', {},
    {
      get:{ method: 'GET', isArray:true }
    });
}]);
```

Client Controller

```
angular.module('alls').controller('AllsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Alls', 'Jeans',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Alls, Jeans) {

      $scope.search = function(){
            Alls.get({issuename: $scope.issueinput},function(response){
                $scope.alls = response;
            });
     }; 
};
```

Client View

```
<section data-ng-controller="AllsController">
<div class="page-header"> 
    <h1>Alls</h1></div>
    <div class="Search">
        <h2>Search Section</h2>
        <label>Search</label> :  <input data-ng-model="issueinput"></input> {{issueinput}}
        <button data-ng-click="search()">Search</button>
    </div>

    <br></br><br></br>
    <h2>Result Section</h2>

    <div class="list-group">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="all in alls">
                    <td data-ng-bind="all.name"></td>
                    <td data-ng-bind="all.color"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Server Controller

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {

    var searchParam = req.body.issuename;

    searchParam = 'Jeans';  // Comment Out or Not //

    mongoose.model(searchParam).find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, alls) {
        res.jsonp(alls);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the "issuename" parameter in your $resource declaration via "@"-notation.
Like so:

```
angular.module('alls').factory('Alls', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('alls/:issuename', {issuename: '@issuename'},
    {
      get:{ method: 'GET', isArray:true }
    });
}]);
```

This will tell your resource to take the property "issuename" from the object being posted when you call `Alls.get({issuename: $scope.issueinput}`

You can read more about that in the [$resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: The problem might be somewhere else. Do you have any server logs to verify what URL is being requested? Is it "http://servername/alls/:issuename" or like "http://servername/alls/Jeans"? If it is the latter, then you need to search the problem in node.js, not angular

Comment: I really Appreciate your help

I Just checked it; I have this :
GET /alls/Jeans
And an Error Which says:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Jeans" at path "_id"

Do you have any Idea What is wrong???

Comment: You should probably update your question with node.js code, because your angular code seems to work ok. There is some problem with the way you pass the request into the "exports.list" function.